# What is kubeflow gpu resource node allocation criteria?

Tags: kubeflow

I’m curious about the Kubeflow GPU Resource. I’m running the job below.
The only part where I specified the GPU Resource is on first container with only 1 GPU. However, the event message tells me `0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu`.
Why is this job searching for 4 nodes though I specified only 1 GPU resource? Does my interpretation have a problem? Thanks much in advance.

FYI) I have 3 worker nodes with each 1 gpu.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: saint-train-3
  annotations:
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: dataloader
        image: <AWS CLI Image>
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "aws s3 cp s3://<Kubeflow Bucket>/kubeflowdata.tar.gz /s3-data; cd /s3-data; tar -xvzf kubeflowdata.tar.gz; cd kubeflow_data; ls"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /s3-data
          name: s3-data
        env:
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: {key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, name: aws-secret}
        - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: {key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, name: aws-secret}
      containers:
      - name: trainer
        image: <Our Model Image>
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "wandb login <ID>; python /opt/ml/src/main.py --base_path='/s3-data/kubeflow_data' --debug_mode='0' --project='kubeflow-test' --name='test2' --gpu=0 --num_epochs=1 --num_workers=4"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /s3-data
          name: s3-data
        resources:
          limits:
            nvidia.com/gpu: "1"
      - name: gpu-watcher
        image: pytorch/pytorch:latest
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "--"]
        args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /s3-data
          name: s3-data
      volumes:
      - name: s3-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: test-claim
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
  backoffLimit: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

> 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu

This is mean you haven't nodes with label nvidia.com/gpu